# ASP.Net membership for sql server compact database for ASP.Net MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce, webmatrix, sql-server-ce-4

When we start ASP.Net MVC 3 Starter Site Project in WebMatrix.

We get asp.net membership tables pre-installed in SDF (SQL Compact) db.

Now, if we want to create them in new SQL CE 4.0 DB, what is the procedure?

i dont want to use starter site.

Answer (score 1):

What about [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)?

Pretty sure it will be default on next ASP.NET version.

Answer (score 0):

The Starter Site is not an MVC application. It's a Web Pages application. The Starter Site is designed to show you how to use security and membership in a Web Pages application, but more detailed instructions can be found here: [Adding Security and Membership](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/16-adding-security-and-membership)